# I am able to get yahoo contacts on localhost but not on live server using oauth yahoo api getting invalid signature error

Tags: asp.net, yahoo-api

My code is working fine on localhost but generate error on live server for importing yahoo contacts.
it create , 401  error signature invalid.
but working fine in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with Yahoo API services (globally), many persons are having the same issue...

Check the following threads:
http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OAuth-General-Discussion-YDN-SDKs/OAuth-Problem-Random-401-Responses/1385737195291-2ef4f411-df40-4f77-a19c-68cfa03a0cf6

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was stucked in it for 1 week, finding what is the problem behind it...